# Notification for edited Google Keep shared note?

Tags: google-keep

I see no notices on my screen when a friend has edited a shared note. So I get no hint, and I don't read it until it's too late.

Is there any solution?

Comment: While [any changes they make will appear instantly on the app](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6101196), there seems no notification if you're outside the app. Perhaps not a solution, but adding Google Keep 3x2 widget to the home screen will help you to see the notes directly from there.

Comment: Are you the owner of the note and that you have shared with your friend?

Comment: @AndrewT. Is there a Google Keep 3x2 widget for iOS? Or only for Android?